# Angular 12 Set Validators Component

Tags: angular

In Angular 12, I am designing a reusable component inside the project but I am getting the following errors while setting the validator

> Argument of type '(ValidatorFn | null | undefined)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[] | null'.
> Type '(ValidatorFn | null | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type 'ValidatorFn[]'.
> Type 'ValidatorFn | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ValidatorFn'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ValidatorFn'.

```ts
import { Component, ElementRef, Input, OnInit, Self, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-text-input',
  templateUrl: './text-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./text-input.component.css']
})
export class TextInputComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {

  @ViewChild('input', { static: true }) input!: ElementRef;
  @Input() type = "text";
  @Input() label!: string;

  constructor(@Self() public controlDir: NgControl) {
    this.controlDir.valueAccessor = this;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const control = this.controlDir.control;
    const validator = this.controlDir.validator ? [control?.validator] : [];
    const asyncValidator = this.controlDir.asyncValidator ? [control?.asyncValidator] : [];

    control?.setValidators(validator);
    control?.setAsyncValidators(asyncValidator);
    control?.updateValueAndValidity();
  }

  onChange(event: Event) {

  }

  onTouched() {

  }

  writeValue(obj: any): void {
    this.input.nativeElement = obj || '';
  }
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Issue & Concern

You need to ensure that both `validator` and `asyncValidator` are the exact types as for the parameter of:

[`setValidators()`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#setvalidators)

> Parameters:
>
> > validators:  ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[]

[`setAsyncValidators()`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#setasyncvalidators)

> Parameters:
>
> > validators   AsyncValidatorFn | AsyncValidatorFn[]

`[control?.validator]` potentially returns the value of `ValidatorFn[]`, `null[]` or `undefined[]` type as mentioned for your error message. Same goes for `[control?.asyncValidator]`.

Meanwhile, checking of `this.controlDir.validator` *might be incorrect* as in case of it is `null`, the `validators` will be set to empty array `[]`. Same goes for `this.controlDir.asyncValidator`.

---

### Solution

You need to **check that both `control` and `control.validator` / `control.asyncValidator` must have value** to tackle this issue.

```js
const validator = control && control.validator 
    ? [control.validator]
    : [];
const asyncValidator = control && control.asyncValidator 
    ? [control.asyncValidator] 
    : [];
```

[Sample Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ky57mz?file=src/app/text-input/text-input.component.ts)